# after upgrade to .net core 3.0 error"No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44374/"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, upgrade, .net-core-3.0

I upgrade my project that have 2 classes library and one Mvc project to MVC Core 3.0 from 2.2 
whit this page 
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#opt-in-to-runtime-compilation)

1. change .net  `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`

   2.change like this

   `<ItemGroup>
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />-->
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>`

   3.my satrtup.cs

   `
           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseStaticFiles();
           app.UseDefaultFiles();
           app.UseCookiePolicy();

   ```
       app.UseRouting();

       app.UseAuthorization();

       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapRazorPages();
       });`
   ```
2. My program.cs

   public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }
       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup();
               });

but when I run my project get this error

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44374/
>   HTTP ERROR 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `Startup.cs` try this

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
           //Code above . . .

            services.AddMvc( options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });

            //Code below. . .
}
```

and then in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //Code above . . .

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            //Code below. . .
        }
```

and remove

```cs
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });`
```

Comment: I honestly don't know.  I think Microsoft Migration example is for a RazorPages example, not MVC.  When we migrated, we use MVC and I ran into this exact problem, and this is how I fixed it.

Comment: If you end up figuring out why, would you mind posting it back here?

Comment: another think, it work fine, when run local , but when publish in local folder get this error: Assets file '..\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.2' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.