# In my .NET7 project I have to use a critical nuget package that is running stable just on .NET6. How can I rollback my project to .NET6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, nuget-package, .net-7.0

In my .NET ASP.Net Core C# project (.NET7 VS2022) I have to use a critical nuget package that is unfortunately running stable just on .NET6. Therefore I am thinking about to rollback to .NET6.
The first thing what I have tried is to change from project properties target framework to .NET6. But after compiling I have got an error reg. "project.assets.json" that .NET7 is not installed. In the project.assets.json I found several links to .NET7 dll's. I don't know exactly whether I am using them all.

Is there a systematic approach to downgrade to .NET6 without disturbing the current project?
I know that this is not a good solution, but until I get a stable running nuget package for .NET I have no other alternative.

Comment: Is moving forward an option for you? I can't realy tell anything about a "safe" downgrade. That depends on two many project specific details. But what i can tell is upgrading is typically easier then downgrading. Did you look at the behavior when just going Net 8?

Comment: .Net7 was released a year ago, what's this critical nuget package with no stable .Net7 version?

Comment: @DenisMicheal Its a special dll for reading data from an industrial controller (PLC). I think abaout to split that function to an external exe (with .NET6) and run this exe from my main application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to .NET6 without affecting current projects seems unlikely. .NET as a development framework affects code development work all the time.

But for "project.assets.json that .NET7 is not installed", you can usually delete the project.assets.json file under the obj folder under the folder where the project is located, and then rebuild the project.

If the above solution doesn't work you can refer to other answers in the following links:

[get error Assets file 'obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846486/get-error-assets-file-obj-project-assets-json-doesnt-have-a-target-for-netc)